# Android Studio Copy Module

Tags: android, android-studio, module, copy, package

I am trying to make a copy of a module in Android Studio, to make small changes. How can I do that? I found several solution but i did not get any to work. Instead of posting my questions in several old topics i decided to open a new question.

I created a copy of the module-directory, changed the name of the folder and edited the package-name in the manifest. Now i am stucked: How do i automatically change the package in all files and make it a working android-project again? I tried to select the package and refactor it but that would only change the package in manifest or in the project tree but not in the java-files.

Thank you!

Answer (score 30):

I just copied/pasted it from within Android Studio, and that worked for me:

1. In Android Studio, make sure you have the Project view selected for your Project pane.
2. Select module and copy.
3. Select the folder name of your project in the Project pane (this should be the name of your project and the parent directory for the module).
4. Paste it in (it will ask you to rename it).
5. Add the new module to your **settings.gradle** file.

   include 'old-module', "new-module"
6. Rebuild/sync your project (you should see another module option now)
7. Run on your device/emulator.

Comment: By the way, if you are using modules for separate builds in the same project and you do this and your module keeps showing up as a non-Android module (and not showing up in your drop down)...

1. Make sure the .iml in the new module matches the name of module.
2. Click into the .iml file and change old references to the new module name.

If it still doesn't work, close the project and delete the .idea file (feel free to just move it to a temporary folder if you are worried). Then reopen, it will rebuild the project and show up correctly as an Android project.

Comment: My module was not showing as an Android module. My solution was copy and pasting the build.gradle file over, changing the applicationId and resyncing. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

File -> New -> Import Module -> paste module's path 
DONE